# Bootstrap typeahead for django

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I'm using twitter bootstrap in my application. I want to use the typeahead in my app. How can I do this?

Nethan

Comment: I've tried this [link](http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/typehead.php) but i still don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

see working Demo: http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp7b#

Please study this link

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead

You have to use jquery,Bootstrap js, Bootstrap css to implement typehead.
I have done working demo see that, `data-source` should be your options.